# Subreddit utc time convert to datetime (python)

Tags: python, api, datetime, reddit

im trying to analyze the amount of titles and the time in a subreddit with Python. But i cant convert the UTC time to datetime

here is my code

```
hotPython = subreddit.hot(limit=4)

for i in hotPython:
    print(i.created_utc)
```

and i get back this results

```
1523290473.0
1521831644.0
1523750525.0
1523747490.0
```

i tried different thing to convert, but i dont get it

would appreciate if somebody can help

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to get the epoch time, you can convert this to a `datetime` using `datetime.fromtimestamp`.

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime
t = 1523290473.0
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(t)
```

Then `dt` is a `datetime` as desired.

Comment: thank you. and if i want to do this automatically when i want to print out 10000 titles. can i add it to the for-function?